# Can I change the LTE bands supported by my iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, lte

I bought an iPhone 5S in Chile, model A1457 knowing that it doesn't have the LTE bands that are needed in Argentina. It was the only model available.

Is there any way to add the band/s that are missing in order to use LTE?
Via software or a carrier update hack?

Answer (score 1):

No. The missing "bands" are physically missing hardware (antennas).